# Store multiple strings in Array using foreach loop and display in another form

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, foreach

I have a DataGridView in which I have multiple rows say (15 rows). **I want to add some columns value and store them in an array using `foreach` loop**. Then I want to display the array (with multiple strings) in another form.

Currently I am using stringBuilder to store the strings and display, but it only display the last string store in it.

```
 StringBuilder listOrderStatus = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in grdData.Rows)
    { 

        string _idNumber = rw.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        string _orderNo = rw.Cells[13].Value.ToString();

        double _ordTotalSpace = double.Parse(rw.Cells[17].Value.ToString());
        double _ordDoneSpace = double.Parse(rw.Cells[18].Value.ToString());
        double _ordRmainSpace = double.Parse(rw.Cells[19].Value.ToString());

        double _TotalSpace = getTotalArea();
        double _DoneSpace = getDoneArea();
        double _RmainSpace = getRmainArea();

        if(_ordTotalSpace ! = _TotalSpace){
            string value = "Invalid Order: Order number" + _orderNo + "ID No." + _idNumber;
            //I want to store this string in the array

            listOrderStatus.Append(value);
            listOrderStatus.AppendLine();
        }
        else{
            string value2 = "Valid Order: Order number" + _orderNo + "ID No." + _idNumber;
            //I want to store this string in the array
            listOrderStatus.Append(value2);
            listOrderStatus.AppendLine();
        }
    }

    string innerString = listOrderStatus.ToString();
    //This a new form to display strings in simple multiline-TextBox (Never mind, this is client request :P)
    var myForm = new Other.frmDisplayData();
    myForm._clist = innerString;
    myForm.Show();
```

Can any one guide me. Thanks in advance

Comment: This code looks correct. How are you determining that it is only displaying the last appended string? Debugging? Note you can combine the .Append(string) and .AppendLine as .AppendLine(string).

Comment: It doesn't look like the problem is in `innerString` (it should contain more than one line). Maybe the problem is in the TextBox that displays the data. Check `innerString` in debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Are you insisting on using **StringBuilder**?! if not you can use something like below:

Define as global and instead of **StringBuilder**:

```
List<string>  listOrderStatus =  new List<string>();
```

And then

```
string value = "Invalid Order: Order number" + _orderNo + "ID No." + _idNumber;
listOrderStatus.Add(value);
```

then

```
 myForm._clist = listOrderStatus;
```

**Note:**

> > 1. You have to define **_clist** as a List of strings like first code line I wrote.
> > 2. in this case it's not needed to use new line .but if you will want to use do like below:

```
string value = "Invalid Order: Order number" + _orderNo + "ID No." + _idNumber;
value += System.Environment.NewLine;
```

> > 1. you can also use Dictionary definition :

```
Dictionary<int,string> Name = new Dictionary<int,string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

How is _clist used to assign to multiLineTextBox.Text?

```
multilineTextBox.Multiline = true;
multilineTextBox.Scrollbars = Scrollbars.Both;
multilineTextBox.Text = _clist;
```

This would at least be the minimum of what you would need?  Are you able to see in Debug that the _clist has the entire string that you're wanting to display?